# fopen (php) from remote server works only for reading

Tags: php, ftp, fopen

I need to open a text file from a remote server and to write some information in it, using PHP `fopen()`.

`allow_url_fopen` is `ON` (in my `php.ini`).

I can read this remote file, but can't write in it.

Code:

```
<?php
$data = 'some text';
$filename = 'ftp://admin:password@192.168.254.1/web/domain.com/public_html/test2.txt';
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r'); 
echo fread($fh, filesize($filename));
fclose($fh);

$fh = fopen($filename, 'w+'); 
if ($fh) {
  echo 'remote file is opened, writing data';
  fwrite($fh, $data);
  fclose($fh);
} else {
  echo 'remote file not opened';
}
?>
```

Shows:
some text
remote file not opened

What can i do make in write to file?

Answer (score 2):

[PHP FTP URL wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) does not support opening the file simultaneously for reading and writing. So you cannot use `w+` mode (reading and writing). Use `w` mode (writing only).

Additionally, FTP URL wrapper does not allow overwriting of an existing file by default, you need to enable it using `overwrite` [FTP context option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php).

```
$context = stream_context_create(['ftp' => ['overwrite' => true]]);
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w', false, $context);
```

---

*Though this will be all quite inefficient, as you will be opening whole FTP session twice. Once for reading and once for writing. You better use FTP functions [`ftp_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) and [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) over one session.*

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP: ftp://](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php)

> Allows **read** access to existing files and **creation** of new files via FTP.
>
> You can open files for either reading or writing, but not both simultaneously. **If the remote file already exists on the ftp server and you attempt to open it for writing but have not specified the context option overwrite, the connection will fail**. If you need to overwrite existing files over ftp, specify the overwrite option in the context and open the file for writing. Alternatively, you can use the FTP extension.

Also a note:

> **Note**: Appending
>
> Files may be appended via the *ftp://* URL wrapper.

I'm not sure if overwrite means truncate or not.  If so, you can download, modify and then upload and overwrite or look at [PHP: FTP Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php).

More from [PHP: Using remote files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php):

> You can only create new files using this method; if you try to overwrite a file that already exists, the fopen() call will fail.

And then a note:

> **Note:**
>
> You might get the idea from the example above that you can use this technique to write to a remote log file. Unfortunately that would not work because the fopen() call will fail if the remote file already exists. To do distributed logging like that, you should take a look at syslog().

So it seems that you can create a file or completely overwrite an existing one.  I haven't seen an example for append.

Comment: But here (second example) is fwrite with ftp...https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: I have no need to append. Only once create a file and write to it (w+)